# Check if value in array (include is not a function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

How to write if include? condition in JavaScript?

My sample code is here:

```
var a = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow'];
if (a.include("red" ))
{ 
    alert(a);
}
```

It gives the following error:

```
SyntaxError: missing : in conditional expression
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [**$.inArray()**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/) as shown.

```
var a = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow'];
if($.inArray("red",a) > -1) 
{
  alert(a);
}
```

**EDIT :-**

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7d0cfL3w/7/)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [$.inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/) in jQuery

```
$(function(){
var a = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow'];
if ($.inArray( "red", a )>=0)
{ 
    alert(a);
}
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7d0cfL3w/3/)**

Answer (score 3):

**plain vanilla javascript**

you can use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check for the existence

> The some() method tests whether some element in the array passes the
>   test implemented by the provided function.

```
var result = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow'].some(function(item,index,arr){
        return item === 'red'
});

if (result === true)
{ 
    alert(a);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It 's **.includes()**
Not .include()

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-string-includes-method/

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to find a ruby alternative. Are you checking whether `red` is a member of array ?
You can use **[Array.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)**

then you may do it like

```
if (a.indexOf("red" )=!-1) {
```

#### Sample code below:

```js
var a = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow'];

//will return -1 if not found in array. otherwise will give you the index
var indexOfRed = a.indexOf("red");

if (indexOfRed!=-1)
{ 
    alert("red was found at index - "+indexOfRed);
}
```